# How to look for a value in SQL filtered in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring

I will try to explain what i need through examples.

i have 2 tables

```
TableA
ID  Name
1   John
2   Mary

TableB
ID  IDNAME
1   1#ab
2   1#a
3   2#ac
```

So what i need is to select every id from TableB and get the name from tableA using the subtring_index function in tableB.IDNAME.

```
Example
SELECT `ID`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`IDNAME`, '#', 1) AS 'NAME' FROM `tableB`
```

This will return the below result, but instead of the id value in the NAME column i want to get the correspond name from the tableA

```
TEMP Table
ID  NAME
1   1         <= John
2   1         <= John
3   2         <= Mary
```

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select b.*, a.name
from b left join
     a
     on substring_index(b.idname, '#', 1) = a.id;
```

You don't need `substring_index()`.  An alternative method uses `like`:

```
select b.*, a.name
from b left join
     a
     on b.idname like concat(a.id, '#%');
```

Comment: Thanks it really help, i adjust that to my needs and its working.. Another question.. If i need to make that kind of link to another table how can i do it?